# Can bloodstreams be interconnected?

Tags: blood-circulation, liver, blood-donation

Novice question. Say we have a mother and child with known exactly matching blood types. The mother suffers from a bad liver and a bacteria infection in the lung along with antibiotics is causing her liver to fail completely. She is dying. Can the bloodstreams of the mother and child be interconnected such that the child’s liver can cleanse the blood of the mother? Assuming the child is willing to risk catching any infectious diseases the mother might have.

Since I’ve never heard of such a procedure I assume the answer will be no. Why not?

Comment: Hi Daniel Schlaug, welcome to Medical Sciences. Questions here are required to show results of prior research. As described in [the help center](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and [this meta post](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/q/411), this demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and helps you get more specific and relevant answers. Please [edit] your question with links to or references to what you've found in your search. Otherwise your question may be closed.

Comment: Note also that immune systems are more complicated than blood type. See [Graft versus host disease](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graft-versus-host_disease) and [Human leukocyte antigen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_leukocyte_antigen)

Comment: In addition, given the close family relationship and the risk of a similar reaction to the antibiotics, why would a physician chose to risk the son's life when there are alternatives?

Comment: And then there's the problem of simple capacity. Can a child's liver, kidneys, etc. handle a 2-3x increase in blood volume?

Comment: This scenario has practical, ethical and physical implications that make it quite untenable, but what about a mother with a newborn who (say) experiences sudden liver failure? After all, their bloodstreams *were* connected until a short while ago.

Comment: @Ottie That is **not true**; the placenta separates maternal from fetal blood.

Comment: @IanCampbell Thanks for letting me know. I did my research without collecting links since I didn't know about this but I'll try to revisit it and gather references. I'll look into your suggested resources as well.

Comment: @LittlePickle. The presumption is that the liver condition is preexisting and the current infection is just the last straw pushing the liver over its limit.

Comment: @CareyGregory My understanding is that one can get by with ~1/10 of one's liver implying that there is some 10x redundancy in a healthy person.

Comment: @Ottie I'd be very keen to hear if you'd be willing to expand on what those implications are.